# Gmail-API request quota at a user level

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, quote

*Note: This question is about something that I do not understand in the documentation here:*
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota#concurrent_requests

### Concurrent Requests

> The Gmail API enforces a per-user concurrent request limit (in
>   addition to the per-user rate limit). This limit is shared by all
>   Gmail API clients accessing a given user and ensures that no API
>   client is overloading a Gmail user mailbox or their backend server.

```
 enforces a per-user concurrent request limit (in addition to the per-user rate limit).
```

I do not find what is the 'per-user concurrent request' anywhere in their documentation. Whereas the per-user rate limit is found at the top in the same page.
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota#top_of_page

Comment: It may be that they have simply chosen not to document the limit, to avoid people gaming it.

Answer (score 2):

> The Gmail API enforces a per-user concurrent request limit (in addition to the per-user rate limit). This limit is shared by all Gmail API clients accessing a given user and ensures that no API client is overloading a Gmail user mailbox or their backend server.

The confusion here is the difference between `per-user concurrent request limit` and `per-user rate limit`

Lets say I make an app that lets users read from their Gmail account.  I am going to be limited by the number of request each user can make though **MY** app the limit is  `per-user rate limit`

Now lets say the user installs your app which also allows them to access their Gmail account.   You are also limited to how fast the user can access the api via the `per-user rate limit`.

However both of our APPs and the gmail and inbox apps are are all running with the same  `per-user concurrent request limit`  concurrent meaning across all of the apps the user is using.

the  `per-user concurrent request limit` is probably there to ensure that a developer doesn't create a number of different projects and rip data using all of them.

To my knowledge  `per-user concurrent request limit` is not documented its a stealth limit and i have never seen anyone who has been able to nail down exactly what the numbers are for the concurrent limits in Google APIs.   With the exception of the Google Analytics API which is 10000 not including the google analytics website and the official mobile apps

**Example:**

per-user rate limit

1. User number one logs in and lists all of his emails he has 10 user gets no error.
2. User number two logs in, he has 1000 emails and your application tries
   to select them all out in 1 second. You are going to get a rate limit error for this user.  You are flooding google.
   However apps by other developers *will be able* to access the user inbox via the API

per-user concurrent

1. user number one is only running your application. logs in and lists all of his emails he has 10 user gets no error.
2. User number two is running your application and 20 other applications by other developers.  Tries lists all of his emails assuming he has done this on all the applications at the same time he may end up getting an error.

These errors are user based due to the name Per-user in the name of the limit.

**Example 2:**

Lets look at the Google analytics API because i know the hard numbers for this api.

- A user using your app can max make 100 requests over 90 seconds. (User-app based)
- An application can make max 50000 requests a day.  (App Based)
- An all Applications can max make 10000 requests a day against a view (concurrent app based)

Comment: Note: Comment edited.
@DalmTo - Based on your answer, I assume that the `per-user rate` limit is _app based_ on _not_ user based.
ie: For the same user, using App1 250 quota units can be requested per second and using the App2 250 quota units can be requested for the same second?

Comment: They are both user based.    The user who has authenticate an app.  or in the case of concurrent **apps**

Comment: Hmm, this makes me wonder as to why two different limits exist then?
If the `per-user rate` limit is user based, is that not enough to prevent a developer from overloading a user's mailbox? Why the `per-user concurrent` limit then? 
They exist because `per-user rate limit` deals with _quota units_ and the `per-user concurrent` limit deals with the _total number of requests_?

Comment: To prevent one user from installing multiple apps and spamming i would think.    On a developer running the same application with a number of diffrent project ids

Comment: Ok. Strangely, I found that even when the `per-user rate limit` is triggered I am able to access my mailbox via the web gmail interface

Comment: _I am going to be limited by the number of request each user can make though **MY app the limit is per-user rate limit**_  

I am a little confused with the `per user rate limit`. Based on your answer it seems like it is App Based, where as per the comments it is user based ( ie: limit is shared across all the apps installed by the user.

Comment: (user rate limit) A user logs in using your app you are limited to how fast this user can make requests using your app.     (per-user concurrent) You are also limited to how many requests this user can make using every app they may have installed and running across all apps.     (Its confusing i know)

Comment: Ah that makes it clear! So, some other app hitting the user-rate limit on the user's inbox **will not cause** the user-rate limit to be triggered on my app ( provided concurrent requests limit is not reached )

Comment: I just gave you two examples in the answer.  Its really confusing.