# Gmail API Limit

Tags: php, gmail-api, google-api-client

I use Gmail API to get users emails from Google using `scope(email)` and It does work great.

**However**, As mentioned in [this Google article](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota) Not only I have `1,000,000,000` Daily quota but also `getProfile` Method cost me only 1 quota.

**So**, Doing some math, I should be able to Sign In `1,000,000,000` Users to my Website daily.

**But**, That's not the case, Actually Google allow me for only `10,000` Requests daily.

**What I need to  know:**

1. **Why is that?** (`1,000,000,000 Quota => 10,000 Requests`).
2. **Is there another way to get Google Users email without using Google API Client?**
3. **How many Sign In requests can I send to google Daily?**

> Note: I have no interest in Google `access token` since I generate my
>   own `access token` for every user (**I only need the email**).

**Thank you!**

Comment: Are you actually reaching this `10,000 Requests` limit? Are you getting any error? If that's  not the case, how do you know that you're only allowed to `10,000` daily requests?

Comment: @Iamblichus Actually no. However, while I'm doing some tests with the API I saw that Google did count those requests but that didn't decrease my 10,000 limit!
The reason I'm asking this question is because we're still in production mode and once we go live we expect a lot more requests that 10,000!

Comment: Does this helps you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383624/gmail-api-request-quota-at-a-user-level

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier I don't think so. But Thank you!

Comment: I still don't know where you get that `10,000` limit from. Also if you want to use `getProfile`, you should use one of the scopes provided [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/getProfile#auth).

Answer (score 1):

You are not using Gmail API. Gmail API is intended to interface with a Google user's Gmail mailbox (sent/received emails). OAUth scope `email` does not grant you any access to Gmail API. What it does allow is access to get the Google user's email address (may be @gmail.com or may be another domain).

See [Google's list of OAuth scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#google_sign-in). `email` is listed under Google Sign-in.

To my knowledge, there are no quotas around usage of `email` scope and sign-in.

Comment: I do use Gmail API because Google plus API Isn't supported anymore! And yes you're right the `email scope` isn't a Gmail API `scope` but It does work!

**So**, do you know another method I could be gathering users emails?

Thank you for answering the question. I do think the same (there may be no limit because I couldn't find anything about email scope quota).